# Can "show-stopper" have a negative connotation?

Tags: single-word-requests, ambiguity

If not, what word do I mean to use when I use "show-stopper" negatively?

It seems that in high-tech culture a show-stopper is a development problem that prevents forward progress, or an unacceptable outcome. (At least in a non-english-speaking high-tech culture.)

My wife called me on it this morning when I used show-stopper in this context.

When I stopped to think about it, I couldn't think of the word or phrase I should be using that I seem to have confused with show-stopper.

Comment: Wait, what is your question? Of course, as something that stops progress it does have a negative connotation, similarly to roadblock or obstacle, just as you wrote it. So what are you asking about?

Comment: @SF The point, as Dr.Dredel says below, is that a "show-stopper" is in essence a positive phrase- something so amazing the show simply cannot continue afterwards. Maybe it is a British phrase.

Comment: +1 I just wrote a paper and a reviewer mentioned that I'd used the phrase "show-stopping" incorrectly.  I've always heard it with a negative connotation, mostly in software development.  E.g., "this bug is a show-stopper."  I don't recall hearing it with a positive connotation, but Googling suggests that it's usually positive.  Today I Learned.

Answer (score 8):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Showstopper
Show-Stopper in the theatrical sense is an expression referring to something truly dazzling.  `"The triple somersault in the dance that starts the second act is a show stopper"`

The show has to stop for applause... it can't keep going if the crowd is on its feet cheering.

Of course you're correct that show stopper in the world of technology and business is an impediment to progress which must be cleared to proceed, and in that sense is entirely negative.

Comment: +1 I just wrote a paper and a reviewer mentioned that I'd used the phrase "show-stopping" incorrectly. I've always heard it with a negative connotation, mostly in software development. E.g., "this bug is a show-stopper." I don't recall hearing it with a positive connotation, but Googling suggests that it's usually positive. Today I Learned.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard the term *showstopper* used in the way you used it. I would have used the word *bottleneck*, which has a definition of ["a hindrance to progress or production"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bottleneck)  or ["a phenomenon where the performance or capacity of an entire system is limited by a single or limited number of components or resources."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottleneck)

Comment: I assure you it is used. Bottleneck is something that considerably slows the progress. Showstopper stops it entirely until it is removed.

Comment: @SF., Do you have a source you can cite? I would like to learn this definition.

Comment: http://catb.org/jargon/html/S/showstopper.html  Google: *showstopper bugzilla* if you want to spot the usage "in the wild".

Comment: @SF., Thank you. I feel like I learned something new.